# Reducing array / subarray / object based on keys of another array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm trying to reduce an object based on an array

Note that this is an instance of Builder `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` to be used with a datatable using vue.js. Also note that this should be dynamic, I'd like to add something to the `getRelationshipValues` array and have it filter it down based on the list within `relationships[]`.

#### Array

```
{  
   data:{  
      table:"minutes",
      records:[  ],
      relationships:[  
         { ... },
         {  
            id:2,
            chapter_id:2,
            brother_id:14,
            started_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            location:"John's Rotisserie",
            status:"Under Review",
            financial_report:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mollis diam dolor, at porttitor libero congue ut. Nunc facilisis enim vitae felis tempus, nec commodo est ornare. Integer auctor, felis nec blandit scelerisque, elit enim luctus libero, blandit ullamcorper orci libero quis quam. Fusce vehicula nulla facilisis quam varius, et vehicula urna malesuada.",
            ended_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            created_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            updated_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            chapter:{  
               id:2,
               name:"Western Islip"
            }
            brother:{
               id:14
               full_name:"Jonathan West"
            }
         },
         { ... }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Constraint

Another array I'd like to compare the keys and only return it's corresponding value from it's respective key from above:

```
public function getRelationshipValues()
{
    return [
        'chapter' => 'name',
        'brother' => 'full_name'
    ];
}
```

Once reduced the object should look like so:

```
{  
   data:{  
      table:"minutes",
      records:[  ],
      relationships:[  
         { ... },
         {  
            id:2,
            chapter_id:2,
            brother_id:14,
            started_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            location:"John's Rotisserie",
            status:"Under Review",
            financial_report:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mollis diam dolor, at porttitor libero congue ut. Nunc facilisis enim vitae felis tempus, nec commodo est ornare. Integer auctor, felis nec blandit scelerisque, elit enim luctus libero, blandit ullamcorper orci libero quis quam. Fusce vehicula nulla facilisis quam varius, et vehicula urna malesuada.",
            ended_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            created_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            updated_at:"2008-05-15 22:23:00",
            chapter:"Western Islip",
            brother:"Jonathan West",
         },
         { ... }
      ]
   }
}
```

Is this something that can be done using either Laravel's collection methods or PHP's array functions. I tried playing around with it, but couldn't get much traction.

#### EDIT

*I'd like to drop the id from the chapter_name and brother_name and turn it to a string like in the second relationships array based on the keys and values given in the constraint array*

#### EDIT

Added some more clarification, I believe my original question may have confused some. We're trying to iterate through the `relationships` array and only return the `name` and `full_name` from `chapter` and `brother` subarrays respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) method of Collections as:

```
$relationships = $relationships->map(function ($relationship) {
    return $relationship->only(['id', 'chapter_id', 'chapter_name.name', ...]);
});
```

You can further reduce it using [Higher Order Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#higher-order-messages) as:

```
$relationships = $relationships->map->only(['id', 'chapter_id', 'chapter_name.name', ...])
```

**UPDATE**

I think Model's `only()` method will not work with **dot.strings** *(chapter_name.name)* so you can use [`array_only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-only) helper method as:

```
$relationships = $relationships->map(function ($relationship) {
    return array_only($relationship, ['id', 'chapter_id', 'chapter_name.name', ...]);
});
```

Comment: I updated my original question. I realized it required more clarity. Thanks for your help.